# inserting a special character into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, collation, unicode

I have a few characters that are being replaced by a `?`. How do you keep the original character in the table? The character that I am trying to insert is a `ɬ`; Latin Small Letter L With Belt. Is it possible to add this character into the table?

Comment: Please do not speak about "special" characters, even if everyone does this abuse. No character is special, especially outside of any context. They are all streams of bits for our computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to add that character as long as either:

1. the destination column is `NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` / `XML` (`NTEXT` also works, but has been deprecated since the release of SQL Server 2005 so don't use it),

   OR
2. the destination column is `CHAR` / `VARCHAR` *and* the Collation of the column uses a Code Page that supports the character(s) in question.

So, make sure to do the following:

1. Prefix the string with `N` (not required if the current Database's default Collation uses a Code Page that supports the character, but helps in that it removes the Database's default Collation from being a factor that could cause this issue -- reason being that if the current DB's default Collation uses a Code Page that doesn't support the character, then it will be converted to either a "best fit" match, or `?` if no best fit match can be found, while it is being held in a variable or string literal).
2. Along those same lines, if this is coming into a stored procedure or parameterized query batch via a parameter *and* the parameter is of type `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, then the current Database's default Collation does not use a Code Page that supports the character, so switch to using `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` as the parameter datatype.
3. If the destination column is `VARCHAR` / `CHAR`, then be sure that the Collation of the column uses a Code Page that supports that character.
4. If the destination column is `VARCHAR` / `CHAR` and you cannot find a Collation that uses a Code Page that supports the character(s) in question, then you need to convert the column to `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` so that it can store any character.   <sub>( This is what worked for the O.P. )</sub>

For more info on working with Collations, please visit: [Collations.info](https://collations.info/)

Comment: Thank you. Changing the column to be `NVARCHAR` allowed me to store the string with the special character